Display custom dates on x axis matplotlib
Here is my plot:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as mdates


dates = pd.date_range('2020-03-31', '2024-06-30', freq='Q')
my_df =pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 
                        'type_a': [np.nan]*10 + list(range(0, len(dates)-10)),
                        'type_b': range(len(dates), 2*len(dates))})
    
my_df = my_df.melt(id_vars='dates', value_vars = ['type_a', 'type_b'])
my_df.dates = my_df.dates.dt.date

gfg = sns.lineplot(x='dates', y='value', hue='variable', 
                  data=my_df, estimator=None)
gfg.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=3))
gfg.set_xticklabels(gfg.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
gfg.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))

It does not display dates as they are in dataframe:

I also tried to replace gfg.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=3)) with gfg.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval=90)), but it is also not what I am looking for.
How can I get dates exactly as in dataframe?

Remove the loc/formatter and use plt.xticks(my_df["dates"].unique(), rotation=90).

@Timeless You are a lifesaver! It worked!

@Timeless, Interesting, if I replace plt.xticks(my_df["dates"].unique(), rotation=90) with gfg.xticks(my_df["dates"].unique(), rotation=90) it does not work anymore.

There is no Axes.xticks in the API. If you insist, you need (in the code I shared in the 1st comment) to store the lineplot in gfg and replace plt.xticks(my_df["dates"].unique(), rotation=90) with gfg.set_xticks(my_df["dates"].unique(), my_df["dates"].dt.date.unique(), rotation=90).

@Timeless, Thank you again! I need to gain more clarity regarding what it axis and what is plot.
